# Can I access my XML layout programmatically through findViewById

Tags: java, android, android-layout

For example, my layout looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

can I do

`RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);`
`rl.someMethod();`

When I do try I get a NPE, but I'm curious if accessing it like this is feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* access your `RelativeLayout` programmatically. What you are doing wrong is that you are trying to access the layout file in findViewById. What you should do instead, is to specify the id of the relative layout, not the name of the file which contains it. For this, first set id to your relative layout with

```
android:id="@+id/someRelativeLayout"
```

Then after having called `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` do:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.someRelativeLayout); 
rl.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. You always want to create an id for RelativeLayout and mention that id

```
   <RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/a"
    />
```

RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.a);

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible to access this layout as you do it.

You're getting `NullPointerException` though because you're accessing `activity_main` which doesn't exist. Your layout in XML file doesn't have its id specified, and while you're trying to get `activity_main`, it should have id with the same name:

```
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have

```
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
```

Then

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // set layout to the activity
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout); 
// then initialize views
```

You get `NullPointerException` as `findViewById` din't find the view with the id mentioned which is integer value. Also you had `R.layout.activity_main`.

I do not know what is `someMethod()`. You need to look at docs of `RelativeLayout` the public methods

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get acces to created layout add id to your xml and use findViewById
Like this:

In xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/id">
</RelativeLayout>
```

In java

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.id);
```

If you want to create layout from xml you should use this code

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

RelativeLayout layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent_view, false); //parent view is your activity view
```